# Leak in android app: An instance of SmoothScroller was started more than once

Tags: android, performance, androidx, android-memory

After leaving android app I keep getting the following message in logcat:

`An instance of SmoothScroller was started more than once. Each instance ofSmoothScroller is intended to only be used once. You should create a new instance for each use.`

I tried to google this error without any luck. I really don't know where to start looking. Long after quitting app, I keep getting thee messages.

Comment: Is this your app that you are developing? Or a different app and you are noticing it in the logcat?

Comment: Yes, it's mine. I figured out the porblem lies in 3rd party lib I am using. So, I guess I am going to create that functionality by myself. :)